# Netsuite Advanced PDF/HTML text formatting

Tags: html, css, pdf, freemarker, netsuite

I am trying to left-align all lines of text string within a table in netsuite, but the text does not always have the same width, i.e. is not always more than 1 line.
The demo template seems to work okay;
[demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ywqnc.png)

However, when it comes to printing a sales order, the text string that spans multiple lines, ends up adding white space to the all but the final line of text. Similar to `justify` style, even though this is never mentioned in the template.
[actual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1icQ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this CSS to your templates to fix this issue:

```
td p {
    text-align: left;
}
```

[Credit](https://usergroup.netsuite.com/users/forum/platform-areas/customization/bfo/397738-how-do-i-prevent-text-justification-advanced-pdf-freemarker-bfo)